# Create a copy of csv file by stripping off first n rows

Tags: python, powershell

I have a set of huge csv files (c. 30GB each) with gibberish headers in the first 2 rows (this number is variable). I want to strip these header rows and create a clean copy of the file. I tried using the below `Powershell` scripts to first get the number of rows in the original file and then run the `tail` command to write the lines (minus the header) to the new file. However, the `tail` command I think tries to read everything in the memory and the machine becomes unresponsive after an hour for really big files (works fine for small ones).

`Get-ChildItem "." |% {$n = $_; $c = 0; Get-Content -Path $_ -ReadCount 1000 |% { $c += $_.Count }; "$n; $c"} > row_count.txt`

`Get-content orignal_csv.csv -tail 32364557 | set-content new_csv.csv`
`#32364557 is the number of rows in the original file minus 2 (headers)`

Since the above option didn't work for these huges files, I tied `Python` - the script below. But this is too slow as well as it reads into a dataframe - has been running for a couple of hours.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pandas.read_csv('orignal_csv.csv', skiprows=2)
df.to_csv(new_csv.csv)
```

Is there a better, quicker and less resource intensive way of achieving this either in `Powershell` or `Python`?

Comment: have you tried awk? it's better at handling large data set.
I have used it few time for similar scenario for around 50gb file and it ran within a minutes.

Comment: Thanks @AmitKumar, that sounds promising! I have no knowldge of `awk`. But if it's a new software then I can't install it as I've got restricted access. If not, can you post an example script please?

Answer (score 1):

python is slow is hell for this task.
I'd suggest to user piped `tail` with `-n +2` option

> -n, --lines=[+]NUM

> output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM

Or using `sed` for in place edition, which is zillion way faster, I suppose:

```
sed -i '1,3d' file.txt
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-do-i-delete-the-first-n-lines-of-an-ascii-file-using-shell-commands - here's more info.

Comment: I tried `tail -n+4 orignal_csv.csv new_csv.csv` in powershell but using `tail` this way it throws an error `tail : The term 'tail' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`. Can you please help with the syntax to run in Powershell? Also `sed` sounds like a great option but I don't have the permissions to install it on my Windows VM :(

Answer (score 1):

Using bash would be better way to do this then python,
You can use the sed utility to delete line from the file:

```py
sed -i '1d' file
```

If you want to achieve the same thing in python, you can download and use the library
pysed,

Similar way in powershell,

```
(gc fileName.csv | select -Skip 1) | sc fileName.csv
```

I guess you can also try to make a more efficient python script by using memory mapping, by looking for offsets then shifting the data and syncing, look mmap.

But if you are using the 32 bit version of Python then the address space limitation could be a constraint.

Comment: I'm assuming `(gc fileName.csv | select -Skip 1) | sc fileName.csv` is going to be as slow as the one I posted in the question? I don't know anything about `sed` so looked it up and it seems like it's a UNIX utility - is there something equivalent for Windows that I don't need to install (I have restricted access on the VM)?